# Spring boot 1.2.5.RELEASE incompatible with OpenShift Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, openshift

**update:** Log Files from deployment with 1.2.5.RELEASE are below.

I want to deploy my Spring Boot Application to a Tomcat 7 on OpenShift.

This works fine with the spring-boot-starter-parent Version 1.1.12.RELEASE. (Demo Ping service is responding). But when I change the Version to 1.2.5.RELEASE (current realease) I get a HTTP 404 Error on my ping Service (build and deployment does not show any error message).
I want to use 1.2.5.RELEASE because I want to extend my Application to Send Emails with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this requires 1.2.5.RELEASE. On 1.1.12.RELEASE I get the Error:

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar is missing.

Could someone please help me to fix this.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>appdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appdemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>appdemo</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!-- here I want to use 1.2.5.RELEASE -->
        <version>1.1.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>

        <start-class>Application</start-class>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>appdemo</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>boot</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Ping.java (responding with 1.1.12.RLEASE but not with 1.2.5.RELEASE)

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ping")
public class Ping {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody String getPing() {
        return "{ \"ping\": pong}";
    }
}
```

jbossews.log Delpoyment with 1.2.5.RELEASE

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)
2015-08-13 17:30:00.551  INFO 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] Application                              : Starting Application on ex-std-node625.prod.rhcloud.com with PID 217490 (/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/classes/Application.class started by 55cbae307628e1fae70000c3 in /var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews)
2015-08-13 17:30:00.871  INFO 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1d09808: startup date [Thu Aug 13 17:30:00 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-13 17:30:00.967  WARN 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] ionWarningsApplicationContextInitializer : 
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.
2015-08-13 17:30:43.449  INFO 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/var/lib/opens
hift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar]
2015-08-13 17:30:43.462 ERROR 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.convertClassValues(AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:255)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
2015-08-13 17:30:43.549  INFO 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1d09808: startup date [Thu Aug 13 17:30:00 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-13 17:30:43.557  WARN 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1d09808: startup date [Thu Aug 13 17:30:00 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-13 17:30:43.558  WARN 217490 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1d09808: startup date [Thu Aug 13 17:30:00 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Aug 13, 2015 5:30:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.convertClassValues(AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:255)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:90)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 44 more
Aug 13, 2015 5:30:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/55cbae307628e1fae70000c3/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I am confused. The mail starter does not exist in 1.1.x so the error you're having is to be expected. I can't think of one reason why a successful deployment of your app would lead to a 404 with 1.2 and not with 1.1. Can you share some logs?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll: I added the logs from the failing deployment.

Comment: Well, read the warning :)

Comment: I had some trouble getting the logs from the cloud in the first place. The git commit to OpenShift shows the deployment progress and there where no errors shown. But now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I fixed it: All I had to do was moving my Main Class in a declared package.

The way I came to this:

I added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in the `application.properties`:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

As reported by this Bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2124
But this is fixed in 1.2.5 so this was not the reason.

Afterwards I got a new Error:

```
2015-08-14 04:31:51.000  WARN 368699 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:597)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:777)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

This was fixed by moving my Main Class Application.java from the default package into any other declared package.

This Bug report helped my: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2050
also it is not the reason because the Bug is about `WebConfigurationAdapter` and my Stacktrace is about `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`.

Now my Ping is working with spring boot 1.2.5.RELEASE.

I could even remove the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency and it is still working, so the only reason it did not work was that my Main Class was in the default package.

I hope it still works with the other packages I want to add.

Comment: The `spring-security` dependency should not be necessary. If you look at #2050 it has been fixed in `1.2.1` and you should be using `1.2.5` anyway.

Comment: what can I say, after reading the Bug report I thought the same. But I got the Error in the first place and fixed I like this. Is it possible that the Bug came back in the later release?

Comment: That bug report has nothing to do with your stacktrace. Read it again. In yours its complaining that something in Spring Data REST is not found. In #2050, it's about `WebConfigurationAdapter`. It would be nice if you could remove that wrong reference in your answer.

Comment: I updated my post. you are right, I can remove the `spring-security` dependency. And I added a explaination to the Bug-Links.